# Stable singular point using Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, singularity

Suppose we have the following system of ODEs:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y(t)-x(t)^3\\-x(t)^3\end{pmatrix}$$
We know that the point $(0,0)$ is a singular point of this system. We are asked the following:

> Using an appropriate Lyapunov function, show that $(0,0)$ is a stable singular point.

I tried using a "quadratic-like" function, but I don't think I'm on the right path. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Try the Lyapunov $$V=\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{2}y^2$$

Comment: That was actually one of the first function I tried using! But, when it came to showing the existence of $h:[0,R]\to[0,\infty[$ strictly increasing, $h(0)=0$ and with $V(t,x)\geq h(\|x\|)$, I failed finding such a $h$. Could you give me another hint?

Comment: Well, for $\|x\|\leq 1$ you can use $h(\|x\|)=\frac{1}{8}\|x\|^4$.

Comment: You are welcome!